# Pandas DataFrame: Adding a new column with the average price sold of an Author

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe data where i have like 10.000 records of sold items for 201 authors.

I want to add a column to this dataframe which is the average price for each author.

First i create this new column average_price and then i create another dataframe df
where i have 201 columns of authors and their average price. (at least i think this is the right way to do this)

```py
data["average_price"] = 0
df = data.groupby('Author Name', as_index=False)['price'].mean()
```

df looks like this

```py
Author Name price
0   Agnes Cleve 107444.444444
1   Akseli Gallen-Kallela   32100.384615
2   Albert Edelfelt 207859.302326
3   Albert Johansson    30012.000000
4   Albin Amelin    44400.000000
... ... ...
196 Waldemar Lorentzon  152730.000000
197 Wilhelm von Gegerfelt   25808.510638
198 Yrjö Edelmann   53268.928571
199 Åke Göransson   87333.333333
200 Öyvind Fahlström    351345.454545
```

Now i want to use this df to populate the average_price column in the larger dataframe data.

I could not come up with how to do this so i tried a for loop which is not working. (And i know you should avoid for loops working with dataframes)

```py
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  for ind, r in df.iterrows():
    if row["Author Name"] == r["Author Name"]:
      row["average_price"] = r["price"]
```

So i wonder how this should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform` and `groupby` to add a new column:

```
data['average price'] = data.groupby('Author Name')['price'].transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think based on what you described, you should use [`.join` method on a Pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). You don't need to create `'average_price'` column mannualy. This should simply work for your case:

```
df = data.groupby('Author Name', as_index=False)['price'].mean().rename(columns={'price':'average_price'})
data = data.join(df, on="Author Name")
```

Now you can get the average price from `data['average_price']` column.
Hope this could help!

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do that would be using join (aka [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html))

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame([...]) # your data here
df_agg_data = data.groupby('Author Name', as_index=False)['price'].mean()

df_data = df_data.merge(df_agg_data, on="Author Name")
print(df_data)
```